# Integrate Drupal with Extensis Portfolio?

Tags: files, media

Our organization uses Drupal (6 and 7) for our websites, but Portfolio Server for our DAM and photo collections. It would be wonderful if there were a way to import images directly from Portfolio into Drupal without needing to export them and reupload. Is such a thing possible? I couldn't find any modules on drupal.org that would do this (unless there's a way to use services to access an api on portfolio...)